# Error "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" while connecting to Snowflake Database from Docker Using Golang

Tags: docker, go, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to Snowflake DB using Golang. I found sample code online and it works fine when I run on my machine.
When I put the sample code inside a docker container and try to run it, I got below error.
I'm not sure if I need to contact Snowflake DB Admin to get any certs. Anyone faced similar issues?

> [https://XXXX.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?databaseName=XXXX&requestId=XXXXX&request_guid=XXXX"](https://XXXX.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?databaseName=XXXX&requestId=XXXXX&request_guid=XXXX%22):
> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Below is the Sample code.

```
package main 

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake"
)

func main() {
    user:="XXXX"
    password:="XXX"
    host:="XXXX.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com"

    database:="XXX"
    warehouse :="XXX"
    schema :="XXX"
    port :="443"


    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v@%v:%v/%v",user,password,host,port,database)
    
    fmt.Println("DSN",dsn)
    db, err := sql.Open("snowflake", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    query :=`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.APPLICABLE_ROLES `
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println("error in query", err)
        return
    }

    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println("error in reading columns ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n\n %+v \n", cols)
}
```

Comment: Show your Dockerfile. You are probably missing certificates.

Comment: I don't have any certs related to Snowflake. Do I need to get them from DBA?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of Snowflake. It sounds like your Docker image is missing the required certificates. These could be the certificates from your OS, or a specific one from Snowflake.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you don't have the certificates needed to form this ssl connection. I'll guess that you used `scratch` docker image to dockerize your application as most of the guides out there does.

So you can just copy the needed CA's certificates using from your builder image using something like this:

```
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_generate_saml_csr.html#system-generate-saml-csr

Comment: I want to give you a :hug. You saved hours of my frustration.